# INFLUXDB: Summarize stateduration to have total "on" hours per day

Tags: time, time-series, influxdb, influxdb-2, influxql

i would like to write a query in flux that return the total "on" hours in each day.

```
from(bucket: "hass")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "binary_sensor.slave_ch_active_boiler_caldaia_ot")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "state")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["domain"] == "binary_sensor")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "slave_ch_active_boiler_caldaia_ot")
  |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == "on", column: "state_duration", unit: 1s)
```

i found the stateDuration function that return the on time for each period, but i've no idea how to summarize that value in days window because stateduration return several values while "on" and i shoud sum only the last value of each series:

[image]

does anybody know hot to realize that?

Answer (score 0):

I made it

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/monitor"
from(bucket: "hass")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "binary_sensor.slave_ch_active_boiler_caldaia_ot")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "state")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _level: r._value}))
  |> elapsed()
  |> monitor.stateChanges(fromLevel: "on", toLevel: "off")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with elapsedFloat: float(v: r.elapsed)/3600.0 }))
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum, column:"elapsedFloat", createEmpty: false)
```

monitor.stateChanges in combination with elapsed did the trick!

Lorenzo